# How to add margin/padding to ImageSpan in the SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, string, textview, spannable, imagespan

I'm trying to create a custom TextView by inheriting AppCompatTextView and giving the option to add an icon after the text.

Here's my class:

```
class IconTextView(context: Context) : AppCompatTextView(context) {

    private fun addIcon(drawable: Drawable) {
        val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(text)
        drawable.setBounds(0,0, 20, 20)
        val imageSpan = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_CENTER)
        spannable.insert(0, " ")
        spannable.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 0, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        text = spannable
    }

}
```

But I want to add a margin/padding of 4px between the string and the icon. I need help on how I can do that?

I have Tried InsetDrawable but for some reason the icon is not centered after that, it moves down and gets cut in half.

Comment: did you got any solution for this??